# Binary and Hexadecimal calculations

Tags: binary

I got this question on a quiz and was not really sure how to do it so I skipped over it. It was asking whether this statement is True or False.

1001<sub>2</sub> < 5 <sub>16</sub>

I do not remember doing these kinds of problems in my textbook so I was curious as to how I would solve this. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Did you try converting both sides to the same base?

Comment: $5_{16} = 0101_2$.

Comment: @Mick - How was this solved?

Comment: Just compare the LHS with the equivalent of the RHS.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not follow.